# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] - Possible work network issue?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to read content of a file on my work network from my work network.  I copy and pasted a code snippet from a google search and modified it to the below.  Why might I still be getting [Errno 2]  (I have changed some of the path names for this question board)

The file path in my file explorer shows that "> This PC > word common common" and I don't have "This PC" in my path.  I tried adding that into the place I would think it goes in the string.  That didn't solve it.

I tried making sure I have matching capitalization.  That didn't solve it.

I tried renaming the file to have a *.txt on the end.  That didn't solve it.

I tried the different variations of // and / and \ with and without the r predecessor and while that did eliminate the first error I was getting.  It didn't help this error.

(Looking at the code errors in the right gutter is says my line length is greater than the PEP8 standard.  While I doubt that is the root of my problem, if you can throw in the 'right' wrap method for a file path that long that would be helpful.)

```py
myfile = open("z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/abc_abc_ab_Full_Report_12345-1_R9999_962019_9246", "rt")  # open lorem.txt for reading text
contents = myfile.read()         # read the entire file into a string
myfile.close()                   # close the file
print(contents)                  # print contents
```

> Full Error Copy:
>
> C:\Users\e087680\PycharmProjects\FailureCompiling\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/e087680/PycharmProjects/FailureCompiling/FirstScriptAttempt.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/e087680/PycharmProjects/FailureCompiling/FirstScriptAttempt.py", line 1, in 
>       myfile = open("z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/abc_abc_ab_Full_Report_12345-1_R9999_962019_9246", "rt")  # open lorem.txt for reading text
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/abc_abc_ab_Full_Report_12345-1_R9999_962019_9246'

**EDIT**

**DEBUG EFFORTS**
working to figure out how to change directory.  Just in case that is the problem.  Tested this code bit

```py
import os

path = "z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/abc_abc_ab_Full_Report_12345-1_R9999_962019_9246"

os.chdir(path)

isExist = os.path.exists(path)

print(isExist)
```

Received this error

```py
C:\Users\e087680\PycharmProjects\FailureCompiling\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/e087680/PycharmProjects/FailureCompiling/ScriptDebugJunkFile.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/e087680/PycharmProjects/FailureCompiling/ScriptDebugJunkFile.py", line 5, in <module>
    os.chdir(path)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/abc_abc_ab_Full_Report_12345-1_R9999_962019_9246'
```

My intention for adding the picture below is to show how File Explorer displays the file path for my file
[FileExplorerPathScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsX92.jpg)

**EDIT**
I think this confirms that my 'OS' doesn't have my file.

```py
from os import path

path.exists("PCC_ESS_FC_Full_Report_65000122-1_R0016_962019_9246")

def main():

    print ("File exists:" + str(path.exists('PCC_ESS_FC_Full_Report_65000122-1_R0016_962019_9246')))

if __name__== "__main__":
   main()
```

Output

```
File exists: False
```

I thought OS was a standard variable for Operating system.    Now I'm not sure.

**EDIT**

Using Cmd in DOS, I confirmed that my path for the z: is correct

**EDIT** - Success

I ran

```
import os
print( os.listdir("z:/"))
```

Confirmed I don't need the monster string of folders.
Confirmed, although explorer doesn't show it, it is a *.txt file

Once I implemented these two items the first code worked fine.

Thank you @Furas

Comment: I noticed in reading another question that maybe the spaces in my file path might be a problem.  If that could be it, how does one represent spaces?

Comment: if you use `/` instead of \ then you don't need double `//` in `C://` but `C:/` - and this can make problem.

Comment: @furas When I change from / to \ I get "SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 76-77: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape"    So then I have to add an r in front of the string and I return to the file not found error

Comment: Why you open(C:/...) in your code and error output says Z:/ ??

Comment: char \ has special meaning in text - ie. `\n`, `\t` - and then you have to use `r` or double \\ to remove this meaning. So keep / . But double // in C:// rather is not correct path - it is not `http://` or `ftp://` which need double //

Comment: sorry @Wonka that was two iterations of debugging cut and pasted into one StackOverflow.  I realized that it was Z after originally testing it with C.  I will correct my question.

Comment: @furas I changed it to ("z:/abcdefg/abc123_...    and received the same error

Comment: Might be a good idea to use os.path.join() to create your path. Also, to represent spaces wrap the entire directory in double quotes, ex: /"word common common"/.

Comment: I would start at `os.listdir("z:/")` to see files/folders which Python can see. Maybe there is really problem if it is network disk.

Comment: @furas   I created a code bit with the two lines:  `Import os      os.listdir("z:/")` and it didn't print anything out, nor give me an error.  That probably means I am missing something super obvious and fundamental.

Comment: if you run it in script/file then you need `print( os.listdir("z:/") )` to display it. But if you don't have error then it seems it can work with "z:/". Now I have other idea. Windows usually doesn't display file extensions so your file may have extension which you don't see in Windows but you have to use this extension to open file. maybe use `listdir("z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/")` to see filenames in this folder.

Comment: @furas  Well that definitely helped me get closer.  It confirmed that i should only be using the folder starting at /Users and none of the stuff before.  It also confirmed that I need to use the *.txt as the extension.

Answer (score 0):

To open and read a file specify the filename in your path:

```
myfile = open("U:/matrix_neo/word common common/hello world.txt", "rt")  # open file
contents = myfile.read()         # read the entire file into a string
myfile.close()                   # close the file
print(contents)                  # print contents
```

The U: is a mapped drive in my network.
I did not find any issue with your change dir example. I used a path on my U: path again and it returned True.

```
import os
path = "U:/matrix_neo/word common common"
os.chdir(path)
isExist = os.path.exists(path)
print(isExist)
```

The check the attributes on the directory that you are trying to read from. Also try to copy the file to a local drive for a test and see if you can read the file and also check if it exists.

This is an alternative to the above and uses your path to make sure that the long file path works:

```
import os

mypath = "z:/abcdefg/abc123_proj2/word_general/word common common/Users/Mariee/Python/abc_abc_ab_Full_Report_12345-1_R9999_962019_9246"
myfile = 'whatever is your filename.txt'
if not os.path.isdir(mypath):
  os.makedirs (mypath)
file_path = os.path.join(mypath, myfile)

print(file_path)

if os.path.exists(file_path) is True:
  with open(file_path) as filein:
    contents = filein.read()
    print(contents)
```

I tested this code using a long csv file.,Replace the variable myfile with whatever is your file name.